# Jquery image slider how to auto play

Tags: jquery, slider

I want to add an autoplay from my slider jquery section. What can i do this ?
   I have a next & a prev button but I want to add an auto-play and also when mouse hover over image that slide automatically stopped

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.photo_category').showFeatureText();
        $(".thumbs a").click(function () {
            var imgpath = $(this).attr("href");
            var imgalt = $(this).attr("alt");
            $("#placeholder").attr({
                src: imgpath,
                alt: imgalt
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    $.fn.showFeatureText = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var box = $(this);
            var text = $('span', this);
            text.css({
                display: 'block',
                position: 'absolute',
                top: '0',
                left: '0'
            }).hide();
            box.hover(function () {
                text.slideDown("fast");
            }, function () {
                text.slideUp("fast");
            });
        });`enter code here`
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setInterval for the autoplay and when hovering over an image:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    _interval = setInterval("changeSlides", 4000); //Start autoplay

    $('image').hover(function(){
        clearInterval(_interval); //Stop the autoplay
    }, function(){
        _interval = setInterval("changeSlides", 4000); //Start autoplay
    });
});

function changeSlides(){
    //Change slides
}
```

Comment: I've changed my answer to where you should put the code. For complete code please show us your html. The function changeSlides can be used for the next button. If you like my answer please vote it and approve it.